# Problem tracking the mouse in pygame for mobile

Tags: python, mobile, pygame

I am making a visual novel that includes a fishing minigame in pygame and i want it to run on mobile devices as well. On PC it works like charm, using the arrows. But im having a hard time with the mobile version. My problem is: i have a fishing rod that can extend on x axis, a string that is attached to that rod and moving in the same time with the rod. The string is a bit realistic, made up by segments,being influenced by the "gravity", speed etc so it can bend, having the physics of a real string. On pc i can track what key is pressed so i can assing to that key the direction the rod need to extend(left arrow or right arrrow), but on mobile devices i can't do that. I am only having the pos function that tracks where the screen was touched but i can't track the direction if the player is holding and dragging his finger in any direction. I tried to append those positions to a list, and checking if the second-to-last position is greater or lower than the last one, but it didn't work.

```
if ev.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN or ev.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                dx, dy = pygame.mouse.get_rel()
                self.mobile_extend(ev.pos,dx,dy)
```

This is where i'm calling the method. I was using get_rel() hoping it will track the new position but no results.

```
def mobile_extend(self,ev_pos,dx,dy):
        
        x,y = ev_pos
        force = .088 + uniform(-0.1/16.0, 0.4/16.0) 
        if dx < x: ################################left side:
            for segment in self.line.segments[::-1]:
                self.rod_end[0] -= 1
                segment.pos[0] -= 8
            
                segment.angle = min(85 * pi, segment.angle + force)
                force *= .99
            self.length -= 2 
            self.line.render(self.rod_end)
        elif dx > x:################################right side:
            self.flip = 0
            for segment in self.line.segments[::-1]:
                self.rod_end[0] += 1
                segment.pos[0] += 8
                segment.angle = max(75 * pi, segment.angle - force)
                force *= .99
            self.length += 2
            self.line.render(self.rod_end)
```

So as you can see i have different values required for the physics, based on directions. But i can't track the direction of the touch moving. If you have any solutions please help!

Comment: What method/packaging allows you to use PyGame on a "mobile"?  I started playing with Kivy, and to simulate an on-screen joystick, I drew an overlaid circle in the corner of the display, using touches to the segments of the circle as directional keys.

Comment: @Kingsley I use ren'py. I made last night a similar thing...some arrows so the player can control the direction. They work a bit ok...the only this is you have to move your finger on that button so it can get input